# Google Firebase Auth execption (FirebaseUiException: Code: 7, message: 7)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using FirebaseAuth for my project.
It was no problem for few weeks but suddenly, my app cannot login to firebase with error of code 7.

--------- Here is the stack trace -------------------------------------

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 7, message: 7: 
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:112)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.AuthMethodPickerActivity.onActivityResult(AuthMethodPickerActivity.java:383)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: I checked the error code(7) is ErrorCodes.INVALID_EMAIL_LINK_ERROR. And I tried it in my android simulator with gmail login

Comment: I think this is my simulator problem. my emulator even cannot login to gmail. cannot resolve dns. so, I deleting my emulator

Comment: My problem was, that I was logged into a guest Wifi which had no Internet connection yet. After connecting to the Internet everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this is my simulator problem.
My simulator even could not login to gmail, DNS could not resolve famous sites.
So I deleted my simulator and recreated new one.
Problem now fixed

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with internet. It happens every time when newly installed app logs in with google sign in.

Comment: So if there's no internet connection it causes the app to crash? Is there any way of preventing this behavior in FirebaseUI?